# Special characters turns into � symbol on Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, url, encoding, query-string

In an asp.net project I have an encoding problem. All pages runs correctly except 1. When I try to get the querystring parameters some special characters turns into � symbol.

I did everything by described in here [url encode behaving differently in Firefox and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323009/url-encode-behaving-differently-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer) and here http://blog.salientdigital.com/2009/06/06/special-characters-showing-up-as-a-question-mark-inside-of-a-black-diamond/ but they dont work.

Why only 1 page does run incorrectly when the others run without any problem? All browser except IE run perfectly, and the weird thing is IE throws error in only 1 aspx page.

Comment: what is the encoding of the file?

Comment: Please precise the encoding, headers and type of file containing the character.

Comment: How is the querstring parameter generated? URL encoding doesn't support the entire ASCII range, much less UTF8. The article you refer to describes an entirely different problem. The OP hadn't set any encoding yet expected IE to somehow guess the correct encoding. A browser's default setting is whatever the user decides. Expecting it to be UTF-8 is asking for trouble.

Comment: One way to get round this would be to have a function that replaces the `ASCII` for `regular characters` for the URL (to make the url usable, would be a lot of work depending on how much `ASCII` you intend on using). I do this a lot. For example I usually convert `regular characters` to `ASCII` such as `',"` for a database select/insert, then I reverse the process when I'm displaying it on HTML.

Comment: @Panagiotis I know they are different. I just share it as an example. My webconfig includes this tag <globalization culture="tr-TR" uiCulture="tr-TR" requestEncoding="Utf-8" responseEncoding="Utf-8" fileEncoding="Windows-1254" responseHeaderEncoding="Utf-8" enableClientBasedCulture="true"/>

Comment: Can you show the code that actually generates the URL? For some reason you are either including an ASCII value in the URL or you don't encode the URL at all. Note that unless you save your aspx and cs files as unicode, the compiler will assume that any non-ASCII strings are encoded using your system's default codepage. I think the default now is to save everyting as UTF8, but you may have some pages stored as ASCII. The same holds for data read from a database - unless it is stored as nvarchar, some conversion will have to take place at some time from the db encoding to UTF.

Comment: But how other pages run correctly? string[] sifreyiAl = Request.QueryString.GetValues(0); this line works without any problem on every page except one. I dont think its related to asp.net, it's a browser thing! :(

Comment: Here is a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636073/problems-with-utf-8-character-encoding-from-url-query-string-value-in-internet-e