# Geocoder - Encoding issue in IE8

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I am using Google Maps API version 3 to retrieve a location with the help of the geocoder object.

The problem is that when using German special characters, I am getting undesired results in IE8,
which has probably something to do with the encoding that IE8 performs.

For example, when searching for the german city "Köln", geocoder returns the correct result in Chrome, FF, Safari and IE9 and takes me to the corresponding location.

When i search for the same city in IE8, it takes me to a non-corresponding city in France.

This is what my code looks like:

```
var gcreq = {
  address: searchAddress, // e.g. ('Köln, DE')
  region: 'de',
  language: 'de'
};

geocoder.geocode(gcreq, function(results, status) {

...

}
```

I can mimic this behaviour in Chrome by using the JS function `encodeURI`.
So using `encodeURI(searchAddress)` also produces the undesired result that I've observed in IE8, which is that geocoder looks for 'K%C3%B6ln' instead of 'Köln'.

Is there a way to prevent IE8 from doing this? OR is there a way workaround to send the UTF8 encoded search term instead of the URLified one to the geocoder?

EDIT: I have HTML encoded the search term before submission (i.e. `Köln` becomes `K&ouml;ln`). Surprisingly, Chrome returns the desired result, even when the term is HTML encoded, while IE8 is still failing. Maybe not an encoding issue at all... but strangely enough, errors only occur when using the German 'Umlaute' (ä,ö,ü,ß)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `<meta charset=utf-8">` in your HTML page `<head>` section.
Have also a look at these pages for further references:

- [url encode behaving differently in Firefox and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323009/url-encode-behaving-differently-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer)
- [UTF-8 content encoding problems](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-api/ZCc9wftdI5k%5B1-25%5D)
- [Google Maps API "geocoding-simple" example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

Comment: That was a good hint. In the end, the problem was that I had some weird code which was looking for the wrong parameters in the JSON response of the geocoder. The other problem had to do with an additional URL call to my API where it was looking for corresponding entries in the database to display regional overlays. This one was not properly URL encoded, so it could only find Köln when passed as K%C3%B6ln.