# URL encoding arbitary characters

Tags: java, url, urlencode

I need to submit application/x-www-form-urlencoded data to a web server.
The server expects the data to be encoded using ISO-8859-1.

Unfortunately *URLEncoder.encode(string, "ISO-8859-1");* does not always work.

Any character that is not part of ISO-8859-1, gets encoded as %3F (which is '?').

Firefox handles those chars in some other way that works on the server side.

\uFEFF (Zero Width No-Break Space) gets encoded to **%26%2365279%3B** which is exactly what I need.

Could anyone please tell me how to mimic this behaviour/what FF does?

Comment: Somewhat relevant earlier discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323009/url-encode-behaving-differently-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer)

Comment: It's more about getting IE to use UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

FF converts the unmappable chars to decimal HTML entities and encodes those using the charset.

\uFEFF -> & #65279; (ignore the space in between) ->  %26%2365279%3B

( %26 = & | %23 = # | %3B = ; )

Here is a method that does the first step in Java:

```
public static String htmlEscapeUnmappableCharaters(String source, String charset) {
    CharsetEncoder cse = Charset.forName(charset).newEncoder();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {

        if (cse.canEncode(source.charAt(i))) {
            sb.append(source.charAt(i));
        } else {
            sb.append('&');
            sb.append('#');
            sb.append(source.codePointAt(i));
            sb.append(';');
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```