# UTF-8 URL percent encoded (hebrew) working in all browsers except IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, utf-8, hebrew, percent-encoding

I have a html.file like this, with a local file with a hebrew name like this:
אב.html

The percent encoded link to it works fine with all browsers but not with IE. It seems that IE is translating it not into UTF-8 but to ISO.

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/></head>
<body>
<p>
UTF-8 file name in URL
File name is in hebrew 
<P>
&#1488;&#1489.html
<P>
Percent encoded does not work in IE / works in all other browsers:
<P>
%D7%90%D7%91.html
<P>
<a href="%D7%90%D7%91.html">&#1488;&#1489;
</a>
<P>
Ampersand encoded works in all browsers
<P>
'& #1488'; & #1489 ; ' .html 
<P>
<a href="&#1488;&#1489;.html">&#1488;&#1489;
</a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: "Ampersand encoded works in all browsers" So use the ampersand encoded version? What's the problem?

Comment: Hi, 1. I tought the correct way is percent encoded, 2. the html editors will automatically insert the link in percent encoded.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323009/url-encode-behaving-differently-in-firefox-and-internet-explorer

Btw you haven't actually said what is actually being shown in IE.

Comment: Thanks for the references. So it seems that IE used the locale of the PC to translate the link. So there is no simple solution to force IE to use UTF-8?

Comment: The link shows as xx.html on the status line.

Comment: That other question said to set the content type to be UTF-8 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> which should tell IE how to render it properly. I have no IE available to test.